# CakePHP show parent category of sub category in select box

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to show Category at the top of first sub-category instance in select box in Cake.

Subcategory belongsto Category and Category hasmany subcategories. Is there a way we can do this?

I have already tried showParents=>true in the select box.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to use the [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag?

I'm not sure there is an automagical way of doing this when using just the **belongsTo** relationship.  The following solution is a little ugly but does what you want:

**Controller:**

```
/**
 * Get all categories and subcategories and declare selectBox array
 */
$categories = $this->Subcategory->Category->find('all');
$selectBox = array();    

/**
 * Iterate over categories & subcategories creating a formatted 
 * array that works with Form->input() to create a select box with 'optgroups'
 */
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  foreach ($category['Subcategory'] as $subcategory) {        
    $selectBox[$category['Category']['title']][$subcategory['id']] = $subcategory['title'];        
  }
}

$this->set('selectBox', $selectBox);
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('subcategory_id', array('options' => $selectBox)); ?>
```